# Display a xib view into a UITableView Cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, addsubview

I made a view in a xib file which is loaded in the main ViewController called "ExperienceScreen". Adding this xib view to the ExperienceScreen works perfectly. The problem is that I would like to add this xib view in a UITableViewCel. I am using the following code to do that :

```
   let experiences = service.getExperiences()


    // 3. Loop through the array of experiences
    for element in experiences {

        if let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ExperienceDetail", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ExperienceDetail
        {
            customView.lblTitle.text = element.title
            customView.lblCompany.text = element.company
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell
            cell.addSubview(customView)
            cell.bringSubview(toFront: customView)
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
```

When launching, the subview is not shown in the UITableViewCell. The *customView* View is filled correctly with the xib View. I checked this using a breakpoint. [image]

Someone knows what I'am doing wrong?

Many thanks for helping !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display your xib file as UITableViewCell, then following scenario works
1. make sure your xib class is sub class of UITableViewCell.
2. register your xib

```
//class of xib file
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
  static let identifier = "TableCell"
  static let nib = UINib(nibName: "TableCell", bundle: nil)
}

// In view controller
func setupTableView() {
 tableView.dataSource = self
 tableView.delefate = self
 tableView.register(TableCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: 
 TableCell.identifier)
}
```

call setupTableView() in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Unfortunately it still doesn't show. Do you see the problem in my code :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr2eknaeovks381/Experiences.swift?dl=0 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/op6kg8a4eh2u0i0/ExperienceDetail.swift?dl=0

Comment: In cellForRowAt change

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ExperienceDetail.identifier) as! ExperienceDetail

and populate tableCell as per your need

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to set up your cells all at once.

You should implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and configure each cell using the method `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. In this method, you can call `register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` to use your XIB for newly created cells.

There are lots of tutorials on creating table views where you can find step-by-step instructions on doing this.